# Ignore weak DH in RCurl or curl

Tags: r, ssl, curl, web-scraping, rcurl

I used the code below to download a CSV from the url in the post, but since a recent update of my systems libcurl my curl has gotten more cautious and complains about weak DH parameters, in bash I can ignore the weak DH-parameters with the `--ciphers 'DEFAULT:!DH'` option. I did not find an option to the `GET`, `fetch_memory`, `getURL` functions in the `httr`, `curl` and `RCurl` packages respectively, that does the same.

How can I ignore this errors in R?
(Every other well supported library also works, preferably tidyverse or something from r-opensci)

```
raw_data <- read_delim(
  "https://info.gesundheitsministerium.at/data/Epikurve.csv",
  delim = ";",
  col_types = cols(col_date(format="%d.%m.%Y"), col_integer(), col_datetime())
  )
```

Note that depending on your libcurl version you will not be able to reproduce this, older Versions seem to bee more permissive regarding weak DH-parameters. I work on Debian testing.

Comment: *"... , in bash I can ignore the weak DH-parameters with the `--ciphers 'DEFAULT:!DH'` ..."* - actually, you don't ignore the weak parameters this way. You simply request that no DH handshake is done in the first place and thus you don't need to ignore anything.

Comment: Thank you, then the name of the parameter also makes more sense. A completely insecure download also works in my case, I just download data from a public source.

Comment: As described in https://wiki.debian.org/ContinuousIntegration/TriagingTips/openssl-1.1.1 you can use a cipher list of "DEFAULT@SECLEVEL=1" to go lower than the new default of SECLEVEL=2 which some servers are not ready to follow, unfortunately.

Comment: Cool, I still hope to find something to just do this for just one request, but it's a workaround if this shouldn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since curl commandline utility is available on my plattform, the easiest solution I found was just using this to download the data, with the parameters that work in bash.

```
raw_data <- read_delim(
  system2(
    "curl",
    args=c(
      "https://info.gesundheitsministerium.at/data/Epikurve.csv",
      "--ciphers",
      "'DEFAULT:!DH'"
    ),
    stdout=TRUE
  ),
  delim = ";",
  locale=locale(
    encoding = "UTF-8",
    date_format = "%d.%m.%Y",
    tz = "CET"
    )
  )
```